# Como conectar a uma rede Wi-Fi específica a partir do meu aplicativo?

Tags: android

Galera, estou seguindo o tutorial abaixo para listar as redes Wi-Fi disponíveis no meu aplicativo Android.

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm

Gostaria de saber se é possível que meu aplicativo faça meu Android conectar a uma rede específica quando o usuário clicar na mesma.

É possível fazer isso a partir do meu aplicativo?

Comment: Allef, acho que essa pergunta pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É so chamar essa função passando o login e senha em String mais essa função so funciona para Wifi WPA_PSK e WPA2_psk

```
  public void Connection(String ssid, String password){

    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
    wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
    wfc.priority = 40;

    wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);


    wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(password).concat("\"");

    WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager)   mGap.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);

    if (networkId != -1) {
        // success, can call wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true) to connect
        wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Só faltou uma função para listar as redes para resposta ser "perfeita", pois pelo que entendi o autor quer listar as redes e clicar na desejada.

Comment: Obrigado! Eu já havia conseguido utilizando o conteúdo de alguns posts deste site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/

Comment: Guilherme, se ele quiser listar pode usar o próprio gerenciador do Android, não tem muito sentido recriá-lo apenas para selecionar a rede. Se quiser abrir o gerenciador é só usar um intent `contexto.startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));`